# Shopify Buy JS SDK throwing error on IE 11 -- Promise is undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, shopify

I'm getting the following error on IE 10, IE11 using the standard unedited shopify buy js SDK.

```
Promise undefined    
shopify.buy.js (1762,17)
```

version 0.23

Same code works on IE Edge,Chrome,Firefox,Safari.

Any ideas on a work around?

```
create: function create(type, payload) {
                var _this2 = this;
                return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                    var id = _this2.identify(payload);
                    _this2.store.setItem(_this2.storageKey(type, id), payload);
                    resolve(payload)
                })
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there was a bug introduced around v0.2.3 that caused problems in a few versions of IE - please update to the latest version (v0.4.1), which should be working well in IE 9+ :)